# Turn off FancyBox tooltips in Slider Revolution while maintaining FancyBox image caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, fancybox, jquery-ui-slider

I am successfully using FancyBox with Slider Revolution. Here is the code I have added to my slideshow custom Javascript box:

```
/* change revapi68 to whatever API name is being used for your slider */

var api = revapi68;

api.on(‘revolution.slide.onloaded’, function() {

jQuery(document).trigger(‘post-load’);

jQuery(this).on(‘click’, function() {api.revpause()});

jQuery(this).find(‘li’).each( function() {

var title = jQuery(this).find(‘div.Photography-Textblock’).text();

jQuery(this).find(‘div.slidelink a’).attr(‘title’, title);

  });

});
```

This pulls the image’s caption from the media library and uses it as the caption for the image in FancyBox. The caption also ends up being a “tooltip” that shows when scrolling over the Slider Revolution image (before clicking to launch the FancyBox slideshow). I want to remove that tooltip from the Slider Revolution slide but maintain the caption in the FancyBox slide. I can remove the tooltip by eliminating the code, “var title = jQuery(this).find(‘div.Photography-Textblock’).text();” but this also eliminates the FancyBox captions. Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

An example of a project URL with tooltips is https://donnallyarchitects.com/project/lake-union-floating-home-2/

An example of a project URL without tooltips (with eliminated code) is https://donnallyarchitects.com/project/marysville-house/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data-fancybox-title` to set title for fancybox only (using v2).